# Add files from database project into MSI

Tags: c#, wix

I've got a database project, that contains custom SQL scripts, I need to add the scripts to the MSI folder so that my custom action can pick it up and execute them.

Getting the following errors

HeatGeneratedFileList.wxs(6,0): error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\TestScript - Copy.sql'.

HeatGeneratedFileList.wxs(9,0): error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\TestScript.sql'.

I have created done the actions using heat:

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <HeatDirectory Directory="../Database/DatabaseFiles/" OutputFile="HeatGeneratedFileList.wxs" ComponentGroupName="Database.Installer" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" AutogenerateGuids="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" SuppressCom="true" />
  </Target>
```

This is the HeatGeneratedFileList.wxs file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmp35BC97AC12F21A6F6154759C2D9B5430" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filDEDB241BDDF1A0CD0B001190398F5F5F" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\TestScript - Copy.sql" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp221D9003B2C58612888DBC0D1CEBC730" Guid="*">
                <File Id="filF6EA2F11A51AF10E1517FFB9152307EE" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\TestScript.sql" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="AgentX.Database.Installer">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp35BC97AC12F21A6F6154759C2D9B5430" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp221D9003B2C58612888DBC0D1CEBC730" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I want to run this code from my custom action to execute the two scripts:

```
 private static bool ProcessSQLFile(Session session, string script)
        {
            var success = true;
            try
            {
                var connectionStringBuilder = BuildConnectionString(session);

                var scriptToRun = File.ReadAllText(script);

                var connectionString = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

                var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connectionString));

                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptToRun);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                success = false;
            }

            return success;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I missed the following in my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <LinkerBindInputPaths Include="%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)bin\$(Configuration)\DatabaseFiles\" />
    </ItemGroup>
```